# NestJS, Sequelize lazy loading

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, lazy-loading

Any idea whether Sequelize lazy loading works in NestJS? I haven't found much about it and it doesn't seem to work.

```
import {
  BelongsTo,
  BelongsToMany,
  Column,
  ForeignKey,
  HasMany,
  Model,
  PrimaryKey,
  Table,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Roles } from './role.model';
import { UsersRole } from './users-role.model';

@Table({
  timestamps: false,
})
export class User extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column
  id: string;

  @Column
  email: string;

  @BelongsToMany(
    () => Role,
    () => UsersRole,
    'userId',
    'roleId',
  )
  roles: Role[];
}
```

I'm trying to lazy load `user.getRoles()` (tried also `user.getUsersRoles()`) but it gives me `Property 'getRoles' does not exist on type 'User'. Did you mean 'roles'?` (or `Property 'getUsersRoles' does not exist on type 'User'.`) It should work according to Sequelize documentation: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#fetching-associations---eager-loading-vs-lazy-loading